# textarea width:100% not working in case of absolute position

Tags: html, css

here is the code i am using,

html

```
<div class="chatbrd"> 
  <div class="newmsg">
    <form  action="" method="post">
     <textarea placeholder="type a message" type="text" name="msg" >
     </textarea>

     <button type="submit"  name="newmsg" value="submit">send</button>
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chatbrd
{
height:800px;
position:relative;
overflow:auto;
max-height:200px;
border:1px solid black
}

.newmsg
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
  max-width:600px;  

 }
.newmsg textarea
{
width:100%;

}
```

see [here jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7dyuf1k/)

i want that the width of a textarea should be equals to the width of outer div
but i stucked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d7dyuf1k/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the parent `width: 100%;` which will still adhere to the `max-width: 600px`. This is because the child text area needs to know of what its taking `100%` width.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7dyuf1k/1/)

```
.newmsg {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   max-width:600px;  
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: As a side note, the `textarea` will overflow the container thanks to its borders making the full width expand beyond 100%. This can be fixed by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.newmsg textarea` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    .newmsg
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
/*  max-width:600px;   */
  width:100%;

 }
```

```css
.chatbrd
{
height:800px;
position:relative;
overflow:auto;
max-height:200px;
border:1px solid black
}

.newmsg
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
/*  max-width:600px;   */
  width:100%;

 }
.newmsg textarea
{
width:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="chatbrd"> 
  <div class="newmsg">
    <form  action="" method="post">
     <textarea placeholder="type a message" type="text" name="msg" >
     </textarea>

     <button type="submit"  name="newmsg" value="submit">send</button>
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it is working but i want that `max-width : 600` for `div.newmsg`